# Using xorm sync table in sqlite3 occurs near "MODIFY": syntax error

Tags: sqlite, go, go-xorm

I use xorm engine.Sync2 to sycn tables with sqlite3 driver. But when I sync these tables again, it prompts "near "MODIFY": syntax error". It seems that SQLite only supports synchronization once. However, I never met this problem in mysql and postgresql. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: please share [`MWE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Chandan sorry about the delay. So weird, I just want to reproduce the problem, but it's just gone... Thank you for your attention!